# What does the increase of sequence, that bound above another one, imply?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

If I have a sequence such that its absolute value is bounded above as follows
$$|a_{n+1}|<b_{n+1}\,\,,\forall n\geq 1$$ then if $b_{n+1}$ is decreasing I can say that $a_{n+1}$ is monotonically decreasing too? I suppose that the sequence $b_{n+1}$ is $>0$.

Comment: is $(n+1)$ the index here? do you mean $a_{n+1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, take for example $b_n=\frac{2}{n}$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$. $(b_n)_n$ is strictly decreasing, $(a_n)_n$ is not decreasing (because $a_{2n}>a_{2n-1}$), but $b_n>a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.

The picture below shows the two sequences: black dots for $(b_n)_n$ and red dots for $(a_n)_n$:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks! And if I consider that $b_n$ is decreasing then $|a_n|$ is decreasing?

Comment: No, the same example. Note that here $a_n\geq0$ and therefore $|a_n|=a_n$

Comment: @lay Any further doubt?

Comment: Nope thanks...maybe this result is a particular case...maybe I should do a specific question for that specific sequence!